# How to simplify a formula with integrations by parts?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

I have a huge expression to compute, which contains lots of different terms composed of multiplication of various functions, derived a certain number of times (non derived, derived once or twice). For example, tehre is a term like this:

```
(phi[x]^4*(1-z[x]) + phi[x]^2*(1 - phi[x]^2*z[x]) - 
eps*phi[x]^4*z[x]*Derivative[1][u][x]^2 - 
eps*phi[x]^4*z[x]*(2*phi[x]*u[x]*Derivative[1][phi][x] + 
phi[x]^2*Derivative[1][u][x])^2 + 
4*eps^2*phi[x]^3*Derivative[1][phi][x]*Derivative[1][z][x] + 
eps^2*phi[x]^2*z[x]*(2*Derivative[1][phi][x]^2 + 
       2*phi[x]*Derivative[2][phi][x]))*Derivative[2][z][x]
```

(copy pasted it but I think you get the idea). I'd like to tell Mathematica to also try simplifying by, say, integrating by parts wrt the $z''$ out of the parenthesis. I don't know if this will help (maybe not), but I'd like to have it try it anyway. So is there a command where I can ask Mathematica to simplify the expression also by trying integrating by parts? For example, above $u,z$ have 0 derivative on the border, while $\phi$ is a cutoff. I'd need to generalize these computations in higher dimensions but for now I'd like to understand how to do them in the simpler 1d case. Another problem is: how can I define operations in a way such that Mathematica makes them "stay together" and write in a more readable form? I'll make an example

$$Laplacian [z[x,y],{x,y}] Norm[Grad[u[x,y],{x,y}]]^2 $$

is written by default as

$$ (z^{(2,0)} [x,y] + z^{(0,2)} [x,y]) (u^{(1,0)} [x,y] ^2 + u^{(0,1)} [x,y] ^2) $$

and when expressions get complicated this is unreadable. Also, Mathematica tends to multiply everything together, while I'd like to keep my gradients well separated from each other. The ideal would be being able to have in output something like

$$ \Delta z[x,y] |Du[x,y]|^2$$

and, going back to the first question, the very best would be if it somehow understands how to simplify like

$$ \Delta z u= - \nabla z \nabla u.$$

What I mean with this statement is that it would be nice to be able to tell Mathematica to try integrating by parts certain expression, although I don't know how it could be possible. I can't see why it should regard, for example, $u''(x) u(x)$ as more complicated than $- (u'(x))^2$. I was just wondering if there was a way in which the program, when you ask it to "simplify" the expression, recognizes the expression as an integrand and thus tries integrating by parts like I just did. Of course you'd need to specify boundary conditoons etc, so maybe it's a too complicated task.

Comment: Done, hope it's clearer now. Didn't rewrtite the $\phi$ in proper latex because the actual expression is not important.

Comment: I added also another common (I guess) problem, which is how the answer is written. In the multidimensional case things get very unreadable very quickly.

Comment: Tommy, thank you for adding some more details. It would be best, however, for the expressions to be **in Mathematica code**, and not in Latex. See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951). Having said that, I think this will be very hard to do in a general case. Mathematica has its own concept of "complexity" for an expression, and your simplifications are highly non-trivial, so my impressions is that they would have to be implemented through your own functions. But let's start by getting some code in :-)

Comment: Done it, I hope it's ok, thank you for the help!

Comment: Your request: " I'd like to tell Mathematica to also try simplifying by, say, integrating by parts wrt the z′′ " is not clear. Maybe you could give a simplified example where you make such a simplification analytically?

Comment: I meant like passing from $u'' u$ to $-(u')^2$, but actually I don't see why a program should recognize the latter as "simpler". I tried explaining what I mean by integrating by parts at the end of the question

Comment: 1) First, if I understand you right, you assume that the whole expression stays under the integral, right? You should then specify with respect to which variables it is integrated and what conditions are at the boundaries. 2) In general, you may get a good answer if it is (i) comprehensively formulated and (ii) you give a minimal example. Really a minimal. The generalization you will able to do later.

Comment: (Continuation) 3) To address your main question: indeed, Mma has a certain built-in way to define the simplest form of the expression. Its simplest form may occur to be different from what you regard as such. In this case, however, one can achieve his desired form of expression. For example, the transformation `u′′u` to `(u′)^2` you can do by `ReplaceAll` as follows `expr/.u''*u->(u')^2`. There are no "universal" operators for such "simplifications" though. You need to invent them yourself.

Comment: Well then I guess it's not possible. I mean the universal law would be "Something" * u'' = - u' * D[Something,x], but that expression can be anything